# How to reuse a JSP as view with different request mapping in Spring MVC? Not templating

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Let's say I have this folder structure inside WEB-INF:

```
WEB-INF
- jsp
  - foo
    + bar.jsp
```

And I have a view resolver:

```xml
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

bar.jsp has this content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head> ... </head>
    <body>
        Hello ${name}
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a controller like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/bar.html")
    public void showBar(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", "Luiggi");
    }
}
```

Now I want to reuse bar.jsp in the same controller but using a different request mapping, like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/bar.html")
    public void showBar(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", "Luiggi");
    }
    @RequestMapping("/quo.html")
    public String showQuo(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", "Thomas");
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

Above approach will fail because Spring MVC will search for `bar.jsp` in the root, this is, inside WEB-INF/jsp. I want/need to reuse bar.jsp because I'm basically using the same content, just using different data to fill the attributes.

Currently I know of a very inflexible solution which is to return the whole path of bar.jsp:

```
@RequestMapping("/quo.html")
public String showQuo(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", "Thomas");
    return "foo/bar";
}
```

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Note: This is no templating. I just want to use the same JSP resource for two views only with different URL, as shown in the example.

Comment: Did you try viewResolver?

Comment: @RossiRobinsion I'm already using one. I've added that info in the question.

Comment: Inflexible? Providing the full path of the view is the ordinary approach. What's different about that from specifying just the filename? (Note also that you're absolutely using templating in this example. You just aren't using a layout manager.)

Comment: @chrylis in `showBar` method I'm relying on Spring to recognize the JSP for the view to use in the response by using the URL of the request. I want a similar approach using `showQuo` if possible, or at least the relative path used in this controller. If it isn't, then post an answer explaining that it's not possible and that I should use the ordinary approach.

Comment: I'm not certain that it's not, but it seems to me that that reliance is itself more fragile than the usual approach. Maybe something more automatic is possible, but I simply always specify both mappings and views.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`UrlFilenameViewController`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/UrlFilenameViewController.html)

> Simple Controller implementation that transforms the virtual path of a
>   URL into a view name and returns that view.

The [following blog post](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-url-based-view-resolution-with-urlfilenameviewcontroller-example), lays out all the configuration details nicely. Since you need the model, I've added an exemplary subclass that should give you enough to start from

```
@Controller
public class DynamicViewController extends UrlFilenameViewController
{
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return new ModelAndView(this.getViewNameForRequest(request));
    }
}
```